# Lodash : how to do a Non-ASCII characters sorting on a collection using orderBy?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort an multidimentional array with Non-ASCII characters and multiple objects.

tried this but doesn't worked

```
const users = [
  { name: 'A', age: 48 },
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'á', age: 40 },
  { name: 'b', age: 36 }
]

const nameLocale = users.sort((a, b) => (a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));

const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, [nameLocale, 'age'], ['asc', 'asc'])
```

the sorted array i need would be like this:

```
   { name: 'á', age: 40 }
   { name: 'A', age: 48 },
   { name: 'B', age: 34 },
   { name: 'b', age: 36 }
```

but the responde i got is this:

```
[
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'b', age: 36 },
  { name: 'á', age: 40 },
  { name: 'A', age: 48 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove diacritics with the following code, from: https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2019/matching-accented-strings-in-javascript/

Then it seems like you consider uppercase and lowercase letters equal, so you can convert to lowercase.

Also, `orderBy` takes a function as a parameter, not a sorted array.

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'A', age: 48 },
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'á', age: 40 },
  { name: 'b', age: 36 }
]

const sortByName = (user) => user.name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLocaleLowerCase();

const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, [sortByName, 'age'], ['asc', 'asc']);

console.log(sortedUsers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but somenthing is weird because it still doesnt work.. even using your sugestion, the result is

  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'b', age: 36 },
  { name: 'á', age: 40 },
  { name: 'A', age: 48 }

below is the code:
import _ from 'lodash';

const users = [
  { name: 'A', age: 48 },
  { name: 'B', age: 34 },
  { name: 'á', age: 40 },
  { name: 'b', age: 36 }
]

function sortByName(user){
  user.name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLocaleLowerCase()}

const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, ['sortByName', 'age'], ['asc', 'asc']);

Comment: `sortByName` shouldn't be wrapped in quotes

Comment: sorry for the typo but the result doesnt changed.. its a mistery..there must be something wrong here.. Anyway thanks again

Comment: mistery founded! the tag 'return' was missing in my sortByName function. thanks again!